# Hide a SQL server table partition

Tags: sql-server, data-protection

Is it possible on SQL Server Enterprise to hide a specific table partition from users including admins? encrypting the data is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get more granular than the table level security.  And there's definitely nothing you can hide from sysadmins (or even dbo within the same db) short of encrypting the data.

Why is encryption not an option?  If you can't do it at the SQL level, can you do it within the app?

Comment: Thanks. For encryption, it will make string searches, especially regex, on database strings impossible I thought.

Comment: Depends on how you do the encryption and how you want to search.  If you encrypt from the SQL Server side they you will be able to decrypt to do your searches, given the appropriate keys of course.